# How Long Can an Anacrucis Be?

Tags: theory

Most anacruses are less than a bar long. Often a one note pick up. An example that brings up my question is 'Fur Elise', which seems to have a pick up which lasts for four beats (in 3 time), before the tune proper starts. Is it a fact that an anacrucis can last, well, as long as a composer wants?

Comment: I believe that Für Elise actually ends each phrase in a 6/4 bar, only, Beethoven didn't write it out because he though meter changes would confuse players.

Answer (score 5):

The situation here is that time signature and the bar lines don't correspond to the "beat" of the music. We don't know why Beethoven notated the piece in 3/4 time, but rhythmically there is one beat per bar not three, and the first bar line corresponds to a weak beat not a strong one. So you are correct that, with Beethoven's notation, the anacrusis is four quarter-notes long.

Beginner pianists might not prefer the piece to be written in 6/4 time using half the number of bar lines, or in 6/8 time using 16th notes, but those notations would make the "problem" disappear.

Beethoven habitually used this type of notation in faster pieces. The scherzo of the ninth symphony has the instruction "Ritmo di tre battute" (i.e. three bars of 3/4 are really one bar of 9/4) and later "Ritmo di quattro battute" (i.e. four bars are really one bar of 12/4). See http://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/108612 pages 9 to 12.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCr_Elise#/media/File:Beethoven_WoO_59_Erstausgabe.png the first edition was notated in 3/8. Arguably that first barline shouldn't be there I'd say - just have a long bar to avoid anybody thinking there should be a strong beat in the middle of that opening line, but I don't know the conventions of Beethoven's time (too late for me) - how strong was the idea then that bar lines add emphasis?

Comment: FWIW in the baroque and early classical era it was quite common for notation in common time (C time signature) to shift the pattern of "strong" and "weak" beats by half a bar in written-out repeated sections of music. Looking at the score in your wiki image, I had forgotten that the two-bar rhythm "skips a bar" at the second-time repeat. That rhythmic feature appears elsewhere in Beethoven. I suppose that might account for the "short bar" notation.

Comment: Actually, there is a more radical solution to all this. If you ignore "performance tradition" and take the *first* bar line as the strong beat (so that the first phrases end on weak beats) the entire piece falls neatly into alternating strong and weak bars, makes musical sense, and doesn't contradict anything in the original score.

Comment: The same issue appears in "On Top Of Old Smoky", which is also generally written in 3/4 but has a four-quarter-note anacrusis.  If one were to notate it in 6/8 or 12/8, the problem would go away.  I don't think 6/4 would work for that piece or Für Elise, since 6/4 generally "feels" like three pairs of quarter notes rather than two groups of three.

Answer (score 4):

When your editor suggests calling it a "prelude", you might be overdoing it.  As a rule of thumb, it has to fit in a pickup truck.

Joking aside, the only hard limit is what your editor is willing to accept.  Usually the mark of an anacrusis is that it fits with the beat: for a 3/4 beat, that puts the plausible limit at something like 2/2 when starting with a partial hemiola.  If you start with an actual unmetered cadenza or something which might more reasonably be called a meter change, limits become fuzzy.

But all those are common-sense limits, not hard music theoretic ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of official answer you're looking for.  Four minutes, 33 seconds?

In *Rhapsody in Blue*, there's a trill and a glissando, both of which can be stretched as long as the clarinetist wants.

Comment: Length in bars was what I had in mind. Rubato is another subject !

Answer (score 1):

In popular music, there are anacruses of as many as 7 notes (7 eighth notes before a 4/4 downbeat).  Examples: "Cherry Pink and Apple Blossom White" (1953); refrain of "Cocktails For Two" (1934); "Sway With Me" ("Quién Será" (1953).  Others have fewer notes -- "Early Morning Rain" (6); "Sealed With a Kiss" (6); "The Chicken Dance" (6); "If I Didn't Care" (4).  Seems consistent that it's "less than one full measure before the perceived downbeat."

Answer (score 1):

A strict answer is that an anacrusis is an incomplete bar at the beginning of a piece or section or a piece.  So it can be any length up to (but not quite) a full bar.

A more musical answer wouldn't limit it to one bar. Several people have cited the opening of Beethoven's 'Fur Elise'.   It's a pretty mean definition of 'anacrusis' that doesn't allow that description to apply to everything before the bass voice starts! (Example A).   But what if we extended it (Example B).   Still an anacrusis?  Why not?   And joy!  Either way, the anacrusis has an anacrusis!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By definition an anacrusis is less than one bar long. Thus, in the specific case of "Für Elise", the anacrusis that opens the piece is one beat.

#### Definitions

**Oxford Languages** gives a strict enough definition that the issue is clarified. (Oxford Languages provides definitions for words via Google Search. See image below.)

> one or more unstressed notes before the first bar line of a piece or passage.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis) gives a similarly restrictive definition.

> [one or more notes preceding] what is considered the first beat (or the first beat of the first measure) in music that is not its own phrase, section, or line and is not considered part of the line, phrase, or section which came before, if any.

Steven Laitz in ***The Complete Musician*** (2nd ed., Oxford University Press, 2008, pp. 40-41) gives a broader definition, but one consistent with the above.

> An anacrusis is an unaccented [metrical] event that leads into an accented [metrical] event.

And for one final, again consistent definition, ***The Oxford Companion to Music*** (ed. Alison Latham, Oxford University Press, 2002) defers the definition of "anacrusis" to their definition of "upbeat":

> The "weak" beat of the bar which anticipates the first, "strong" beat of the following bar....

**Image of Anacrusis definition via Google Search**
[image: Anacrusis definition]

Comment: Thanks for all that. Three of those definitions rely on the 3rd note of Fur Elise being regarded as the beginning of the melody. That's where some may differ, myself included, considering the 9th note to be the most ephasised. Hence the question originally. Maybe that's just a special case - true, *most* anacruses are shorter than one bar.

Comment: @Tim The definitions are stricter than that. The anacrusis does not lead to the *most* emphasizes moment -- it's leads up to the next beat 1 (or, by Laitz's more foregiving definition, the next accented event). The definition of anacrusis is unrelated to the melady.

Comment: @Tim (P.S. "The way to say 'thanks' on SE sites is with an upvote...". :-) )

Comment: My bible - Oxford Companion to Music - which is an excellent reference point, says nothing about 'next beat one', so I'm still searching...

Comment: @Tim The OCM says "the weak beat of the bar which anticipates the first strong beat of the following bar." Particularly in the "Fur Elise" case, that means beat 1 of the first full measure.

Comment: Quote: 'Anacrucis. An unstressed syllable at the beginning of a line of poetry or an unstressed note or group of notes at the beginning of a phrase of music.'First used by G.Hermann in his Elimenta Doctrinae Metricae, 1816.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116267/discussion-between-aaron-and-tim).